# How to add a reverse proxy to a docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a docker image running a metabase website instance, which I access like: `<my-ip>:3000`, this image is launched with:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 \
-v /root/metabase_data:/metabase_data \
-e "MB_DB_FILE=/metabase_data/metabase.db" \
--name metabase metabase/metabase
```

This access is not secure and I'd like to use it via https, I tried using nginx to add a reverse proxy but I could not find a way to turn this port (or any other for that matter) into https.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with nginx

1. Wrap your command to `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx:ro
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 3000:3000
    restart: always

  metabase:
    image: metabase/matabase:latest
    container_name: metabase
    environment:
      - MB_DB_FILE=/metabase_data/metabase.db
    volumes:
      - /root/metabase_data:/metabase_data
    restart: always
```

2. Create SSL certs for nginx
3. Write `conf` for nginx

```
worker_processes 1;
  
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream metabase {
        server metabase:3000;
    }

 
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

    server {
        listen 3000 ssl;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/ca.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ca.key;
 
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://metabase;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }
}
```

4. Execute `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: I did this and in the end `docker container ls` shows `90913cc8ce99   nginx:latest               "/docker-entrypoint.…"   54 minutes ago   Up 54 minutes   0.0.0.0:81->81/tcp, 0.0.0.0:444->444/tcp, 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   nginx` and I cannot access the page anymore

Comment: check containers logs, and your page now should be ```https://ip_addr:3000```